# How can I make spheres behave more rock solid and less bouncy - Three.js and Cannon.js project?

Tags: javascript, three.js, cannon.js

I'm working on a uni project with 3D JS, using Three.js, Cannon.js, and DragControls. I'm having some trouble with the behavior of my spheres. Whenever they get pushed into each other and let go, they act like coil springs and bounce like crazy. The problem is, I'm planning on replacing these spheres with 3D models of planets, so I need them to act more like rocks/marbles and less like bouncy balls when they collide.

I've already tried tweaking the friction, restitution, contactEquationStiffness, and contactEquationRelaxation properties of the sphereSphereContactMaterial multiple times with no luck. I've also added linearDamping and angularDamping to the spheres, among other things I don't even remember after spending the whole day trying to solve this issue.

I've inserted the code snippet below for anyone who wants to take a look and see if they can spot the issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
    canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.135.0/build/three.module.js';
import * as CANNON from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/cannon-es@latest/dist/cannon-es.js';
import { DragControls } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.135.0/examples/jsm/controls/DragControls.js';



let camera, scene, renderer;
let world, spheres = [];
let ground, leftWall, rightWall, ceiling;
let previousWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
let previousWindowHeight = window.innerHeight;
const cannonWallMaterial = new CANNON.Material();
let dragControls;
init();
animate();

function init() {
  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  const viewWidth = 30;
  const viewHeight = viewWidth / aspect;

  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    -viewWidth / 2, viewWidth / 2,
    viewHeight / 2, -viewHeight / 2,
    0.1, 1000
  );
  camera.position.set(0, 1, 50);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  world = new CANNON.World();
  world.gravity.set(3, -9.81, 0);
  world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadphase();

    // In the init function, after creating the world
const cannonSphereMaterial = new CANNON.Material();


  const wallSphereContactMaterial = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(cannonWallMaterial, cannonSphereMaterial);
  
  world.addContactMaterial(wallSphereContactMaterial);
  

const sphereSphereContactMaterial = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(cannonSphereMaterial, cannonSphereMaterial, {
  friction: 1,
  restitution: 0.01,
  contactEquationStiffness: 20e5,
  contactEquationRelaxation: 0.02
});


  world.addContactMaterial(sphereSphereContactMaterial);

  const radius = 1;
  const distanceBetweenSpheres = 3 * radius;
  const totalWidth = 2 * distanceBetweenSpheres;

  const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 32, 32);
  const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x2194ce });

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const x = (i - 1) * distanceBetweenSpheres;
    const y = 10;
    const z = 11;

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    mesh.position.set(x, y, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);

    const body = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1, shape: new CANNON.Sphere(radius) });
    body.position.set(x, y, z);
    // Inside the loop where spheres are created, after setting the sphere body's material
    body.material = cannonSphereMaterial;
    body.linearDamping = 0.8; // Add this line to apply linear damping
    body.angularDamping = 0.8; // Add this line to apply angular damping
    world.addBody(body);


    spheres.push({ mesh: mesh, body: body });
  }

  ground = createWall(0, camera.bottom+5, 11, viewWidth, 2, 5);
  leftWall = createWall(camera.left-1, 1, 11, 1, viewHeight+100, 50);
  rightWall = createWall(camera.right, 1, 11, 5, viewHeight+100, 50);
  ceiling = createWall(0, camera.top+2.8, 11, viewWidth, 2, 5);

  const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2);
  light.position.set(0, 0, 55);
  scene.add(light);

  dragControls = new DragControls(spheres.map(s => s.mesh), camera, renderer.domElement);
  dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart);
  dragControls.addEventListener('drag', onDrag);
  dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', onDragEnd);
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
}


function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  updatePhysics();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function updatePhysics() {
  world.step(1 / 60);

  for (const { mesh, body } of spheres) {
    mesh.position.copy(body.position);
    mesh.quaternion.copy(body.quaternion);
  }
}

function onWindowResize() {
  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  const viewWidth = 30;
  const viewHeight = viewWidth / aspect;

  camera.left = -viewWidth / 2;
  camera.right = viewWidth / 2;
  camera.top = viewHeight / 2;
  camera.bottom = -viewHeight / 2;

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  ground.body.position.y = camera.bottom ;
  ground.mesh.position.y = camera.bottom ;

  leftWall.body.position.x = camera.left;
  leftWall.mesh.position.x = camera.left;

  resetSpheresPositions(); // Add this line here
}

function resetSpheresPositions() {
  const radius = 1;
  const distanceBetweenSpheres = 3 * radius;
  const distanceFromBottom = 5; // Adjust this value to position spheres at desired height from the bottom

  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  const viewWidth = 30;
  const viewHeight = viewWidth / aspect;
  
  const startY = viewHeight / 2 - distanceFromBottom;

  spheres.forEach(({ mesh, body }, i) => {
    const x = (i - 1) * distanceBetweenSpheres;
    const y = startY;
    const z = 11;

    mesh.position.set(x, y, 0);
    body.position.set(x, y, z);
    body.velocity.set(0, 0, 0);
    body.angularVelocity.set(0, 0, 0);
  });
}


function createWall(x, y, z, width, height, depth) {
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth);
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xed1c24 });
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
  scene.add(mesh);

  // In the createWall function
  const body = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 0, shape: new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(width / 2, height / 2, depth / 2)) });
  body.position.set(x, y, z);
  body.material = cannonWallMaterial;
  body.material.restitution = 0.2; // Add this line, set restitution to a value between 0 and 1 (e.g., 0.2 for 20% bounciness)
  world.addBody(body);

  return { mesh: mesh, body: body };
}
function onDragStart(event) {
  event.object.material.emissive.set(0x333333);

  const index = spheres.findIndex(s => s.mesh === event.object);
  if (index !== -1) {
    spheres[index].body.sleep();
  }
}

function onDrag(event) {
  const groundPosY = ground.mesh.position.y + ground.body.shapes[0].halfExtents.y; // Get ground position on the Y-axis
  const sphereRadius = spheres[0].body.shapes[0].radius; // Get sphere radius
  const minY = groundPosY + sphereRadius; // Calculate the minimum allowed Y position for spheres

  // Check if the sphere's Y position is below the minimum allowed position
  if (event.object.position.y < minY) {
    event.object.position.y = minY; // Set the sphere's Y position to the minimum allowed value
  }

  // Get left and right wall positions on the X-axis
  const leftWallPosX = leftWall.mesh.position.x + leftWall.body.shapes[0].halfExtents.x;
  const rightWallPosX = rightWall.mesh.position.x - rightWall.body.shapes[0].halfExtents.x;

  // Calculate the minimum and maximum allowed X positions for spheres
  const minX = leftWallPosX + sphereRadius;
  const maxX = rightWallPosX - sphereRadius;

  // Check if the sphere's X position is outside the allowed range
  if (event.object.position.x < minX) {
    event.object.position.x = minX; // Set the sphere's X position to the minimum allowed value
  } else if (event.object.position.x > maxX) {
    event.object.position.x = maxX; // Set the sphere's X position to the maximum allowed value
  }

  const index = spheres.findIndex(s => s.mesh === event.object);
  if (index !== -1) {
    // Implement a damping effect
    const dampingFactor = 0.1;
    const newPosition = event.object.position.clone().lerp(spheres[index].body.position, dampingFactor);
    spheres[index].body.position.copy(newPosition);
  }
}



function onDragEnd(event) {
  event.object.material.emissive.set(0x000000);

  const index = spheres.findIndex(s => s.mesh === event.object);
  if (index !== -1) {
    spheres[index].body.wakeUp();
  }
}

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Do you have any tips on how to make my spheres behave more like rocks and less like bouncy balls? Any help would be greatly appreciated (and would save me from pulling my hair out)! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, sometimes the spheres get so bouncy and act like coil springs to such an extreme degree that they bounce out of the scene, despite the presence of constraints such as walls, ground, and ceiling. Any suggestions on how to prevent this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the property you're looking for to reduce the bounciness is [Material.restitution](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/docs/classes/Material.html#restitution). You could also increase the `.mass` of the bodies you want to feel "heavier".

Comment: Increase mass of the body